# Controller design

Tags: design, control-system, controller, state-space

I was reading controller design using State space model from book by Norman S.

In that topic, the author suggested to design controller by converting given state space represention into phase variable (controllable canonical form) state represention and then designing feedback gains and then transforming the designed system back to its original state space representation.

Also author suggested an alternative method to design controller without transformation but he suggested that this technique in general leads to difficult calculation of feedback gains for higher order systems.

So my questions are:

1. Why phase variable state space represention is most suitable form for controller design?
2. Why not other forms of state space representation i.e. Jordan or obserable forms?
3. Why designing  without transformation into phase variable form leads to difficult calculations?

Comment: In controller canonical form all the states are directly accessible and can be fed back through individual gain blocks. No further processing is required to determine the states.

Comment: @Chu You could post your comment as a valid answer, then delete your comment. Then I will delete my comment about your comment. Posting answers as a comment is frowned upon.

Comment: To add to what @Chu said, ASFAIK, the pole placement becomes a simple matter of matching the feedback coefficients to the characteristic equations.